# Pandas data structure help - dealing with nested JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to normalize data extracted from my database. Among this data there is column called `ExtraData` which is represented in nested jsons. My `ExtraData` JSON can be one of these cases :

```
{"Data":{"Parties":[{"ID":"JackyID","Role":12}],"NbIDs":1}} #One party identified
{"Data":{"Parties":[{"ID":"JackyID","Role":12},{"ID":"SamNumber","Role":10}],"NbIDs":2}} #Two Parties identified
{"Data":{"Parties":[],"NbIDs":0}} #No parties identified
{"Data": None} #No data
```

When looking to extract the values of ID (ID of the party - String datatype) and Role (Int datatype - refer to buyers when Role=12 and sellers when Role=10) and write "" when nothing is present , I'm using the following method :

```
def parse_extra_data(data_str):
    response = {'Buyer': '', 'Seller': ''}
    try:
        data_json = json.loads(data_str)
    except:
        return response
    for party in data_json['Data']['Parties']:
        if party['Role'] == 12:
            response['Buyer'] = party['ID']
        elif party['PartyRole'] == 122:
            response['Seller'] = party['ID']        
    return response
```

Now, when I want to apply this method to my code :

```
import json
import pandas.io.json as pd_json

query="SELECT OrderID, ExtraData from tbl_data;"
test_data= crsr.execute(query)
columns_test = [column[0] for column in crsr.description]
rows = [list(x) for x in test_data]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns_test)
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    test = json.dumps(row['Data'])
    data = pd_json.loads(test)
    data_json = json.loads(data)
    df['Buyer'] = df.apply(lambda row: parse_extra_data(data_json['Data'])['Buyer'], axis=1)
    df['Seller'] = df.apply(lambda row: parse_extra_data(data_json['Data'])['Seller'], axis=1)
df.rename(columns={
    'OrderID' :'ID of the order'
 }, inplace = True) 
df = df[['ID of the order','Buyer', 'Seller']]
```

When executing this code, df is the following :

```
>>print(df)
ID of the order   |Buyer     | Seller
--------------------------------------
321               |          |              
456               |          |    
789               |          |    
987               |          |
```

And `print(data_json)` show only the first JSON from `ExtraData`.

What am I doing wrong ? and how to fix that ? If we take the scenario above as the database input, df should look like :

```
>>print(df)
ID of the order   |Buyer  | Seller
---------------------------------------
321               |JackyID|              #Transaction 1 we have info about the buyer
456               |JackyID| SamNumber    #Transaction 2 we have infos about the buyer and the seller
789               |       |              #Transaction 3 we don't have any infos about the parties
987               |       |              #Transaction 4 we don't have any infos about the parties
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there isn't data from database as example to try to replicate the error, despite that I think the error is in the `df.apply` lines (take a look [how to use it](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)), because you're using a `lambda` function with row as parameter, but it's never called inside `lambda` definition what it means none of columns is gonna be affected by the `parse_extra_data` function.

Example how to use `apply`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: func(x['col1'],x['col2']),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
data = [{'Data': {'Parties': [{'ID': 'JackyID', 'Role': 12}], 'NbIDs': 1}}, {'Data': {'Parties': [{'ID': 'JackyID', 'Role': 12}, {'ID': 'SamNumber', 'Role': 10}], 'NbIDs': 2}}, {'Data': {'Parties': [], 'NbIDs': 0}}, {'Data': None}]
```

Doing:

```
df = pd.json_normalize([x['Data'] for x in data if x['Data']], 'Parties', 'NbIDs')
df.Role.replace({12:'Buyer', 10:'Seller'}, inplace=True)
df = df.pivot(columns='Role', index='NbIDs', values='ID')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Role     Buyer     Seller
NbIDs
1      JackyID        NaN
2      JackyID  SamNumber
```

Comment: I have `TypeError: string indices must be integers` for `df = pd.json_normalize([x['Data'] for x in data if x['Data']], 'Parties', 'NbIDs')` when runnin this.